# C++ How to make a parent class that inherits from subclass components

Tags: c++, include

Suppose I have a class Person that can divide into component subclasses class Body, class Mind, and class Spirit.

What ways can I build class Person so that it can contain both the declaration code and implementation code of Body,Mind,Spirit?

-------------I previously phrased the question like this----------------

Concerning C++
Im interested in including headers #include example.h inside other code, namely classes.

And Im interested in being able to refactor out code into headers whether implementation code or other header code. This is mainly to help me understand the composition more easily. And give the ability to divide code conceptually, even its inside a class.

for instance, given a Pawn class (in pseudocode)

Pawn.h-----------------------------------

```
#pragma once
#include "GameEngine.h"

class Pawn;
{

//I wish to export these declarations into a separate header Pawn_ModelH.h

class Model;

class Model_1;

class Model_2;

//I wish to export these declarations into a separate header Pawn_CameraH.h

class Camera;

class Camera_1;

class Camera_2;

//I wish to export these declarations into a separate header Pawn_PropertiesH.h

float Property_1;

float Property_2;

float Property_3;

Pawn();

};
```

----end Pawn.h

and a Pawn.cpp-----------------------------

```
#include "Pawn.h"

#include "Modelclasses.h" //implementation of model relies on this

#include "Cameraclasses.h" //implementation of camera relies on this

#include "Propertyclasses.h" //implementation of property relies on this

Pawn::Pawn
{

//I wish to export this to a seperate Pawn_ModelC.h, preferrably with include //Modelclasses.h
Model=implementation; 

Model_1=implementation;

Model_2=implementation;

//I wish to export this to a seperate Pawn_CameraC.h, preferably with include //Cameraclasses.h
Camera=implementation;

Camera_1=implementation;

Camera_2=implementation;

//I wish to export this to a seperate Pawn_PropertyC.h, preferably with include //Propertyclasses.h
Property=implementation;

Property_1=implementation;

Property_2=implementation;

}
```

----end Pawn.cpp

I want to end up with just

Pawn_Composition.h------------------

```
#pragma once
#include "GameEngine.h"

class Pawn
{

#include "Pawn_ModelH.h"


#include "Pawn_CameraH.h"

#include "Pawn_PropertiesH.h"

Pawn()

};
```

----end Pawn_Composition.h

and a Pawn_Composition.cpp-----------------------------

```
#include "Pawn.h"
//the other needed includes are now in the component includes

Pawn::Pawn
{

#include "Pawn_ModelC.h" // with #include "Modelclasses.h"


#include "Pawn_CameraC.h" //with #include "Cameraclasses.h"


#include "Pawn_PropertiesC.h" //with #include "Propertyclasses.h"

}
```

----end Pawn_Composition.cpp

Is there anything stopping me from doing this? And is there a better where of implementing something similar to this?

Comment: Not getting the include and pragma directive syntax right would be your first problem.

Comment: I removed the # from #include and #pragma because the formatted was making them bold originally, I can edit them back in if you like

Comment: I advise against.  The preprocessor is already The Devil, even when used appropriately.  This technique is highly suspect.  It is an attempt to make up for a (perceived?) deficiency in the language by highly abusing another bad feature of the language (i.e., the preprocessor).  What you probably want to do is program in D and use template mixins.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm coding for UE4, which uses C++, I'd love to use more advanced languages but alas.

Comment: This looks very clunky. If your classes are super complex, maybe consider breaking them down into smaller entities?

Comment: I'm missing the "why" in your text. What is the perceived advantage that you want to achieve? At that point, we might be able to offer alternatives (like real composition using unique_ptr for example) that work with the language instead of against it.

Comment: The why is I want to divide code into concepts/classes when the code is within the class.

Basically, I want to consider the code as subclasses, which are inside the above class. Im guess Im just confused as to how to implement factoring of code into seperate classes which are used to compose the superclass.

Maybe there is a way to get inheritance to work?

Comment: I guess Im basically asking how to divide a class into subclasses, such that I can include/inherit them in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

> What ways can I build class Person so that it can contain both the declaration code and implementation code of Body,Mind,Spirit?

As far as I can tell, you want to make a hierarchy, where you want `Person` to be the base class and `Body`, `Mind`, and `Spirit` are sub-classes, which are more specific implementations of the base class. Now, I see that in the first code snippet you want to `#inlcude` some classes and use them. I would suggest to **not** exploit this directive and to make [forward declarations](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/) of the different modules.

But you also have some other options. Let's take the beginning example you gave with `Person`. If `Body`, `Mind`, and `Spirit` are some specific functionality that `Person` has, you can utilize [Mixins](https://michael-afanasiev.github.io/2016/08/03/Combining-Static-and-Dynamic-Polymorphism-with-C++-Template-Mixins.html), where you can "plug-in" these different classes into `Person` and utilize their functionality.

Also keep in mind that header files are used to hold the declaration of you code (the interface that tells us *what* we are doing, while your cpp files are the actual implementation telling us *how* we are doing the things)